# issue with .splice() li items and localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, indexof, array-splice

I have a simple shopping list app, where you can dynamically create and delete list items, and they are saved using localStorage. It was working exactly how I wanted, but then I added an amount field to each item, and have run into some difficulties. I think I have mostly fixed these, except for in the delete function 
When you click a bin icon on the list item, it should check the index of the text from that list item in an array, and then the array is spliced, which should delete the item. This works if there is one item in the list, or if you always try to delete the last item, but if you delete the first item in a list the wrong list item is spliced. I must be finding the wrong index, but I don't know what I've done wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

javascript

```
 $(document).on('click', '#enterbutton', function() {
     $.mobile.changePage('#notesPage');
 });



 $(document).on("pagecreate", "#notesPage", function() {

     /*Load local storage items*/
     var items = localStorage.getItem('items') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items')) : items = [];
     var even = [];
     var odd = [];


     console.log(items);
     items.forEach(function(key, value) {
         if (isOdd(value + 1) == 1) {
             even.push(key);
         } else {
             odd.push(key);
         }
     });
     if ((0 < even.length) && (0 < odd.length)) {
         for (i = 0; i < even.length; i++) {
             appendItem(even[i], odd[i]);
         }
     }


     /*Add new item*/
     $('form').on('submit', function(event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         if ($('#newNote').val() == '' || $('#newamount').val() == '') {
             alert('Input can not be left blank');
         } else {
             var item = $('#newNote').val();
             var inum = $('#newamount').val(); //Append this to the arrayItems;        saveToLocalStorage(item, inum);


             //Create the new item and inject to list        appendItem(item, inum);


             $('#mainList').listview('refresh');
             $.mobile.changePage('#notesPage');
         }
     });
     /*Delete item*/
     $(document).on('click', '.bin', function() {
         var item = $(this).closest('li');
         var index = items.indexOf($(item).text());
         items.splice(index, 2);
         console.log(items);
         localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(items));
         $(item).slideUp();

     });


     /*Check item*/
     $(document).on('click', '.check', function() {
         var item = $(this).closest('li');
         $(item).toggleClass("checked")

     });
     /*Save data to localStorage*/
     function saveToLocalStorage(data, data1) {
         items.push(data, data1);
         console.log(items);
         localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(items));
     }

     function isOdd(num) {
         return Math.abs(num % 2);
     }

     /*Append item to html*/
     function appendItem(data, data1) {
         $('#mainList').append('<li class="ui-li-static ui-body-inherit ui-first-child ui-last-child">' +
             '<input type="checkbox" class = "check" </input>' +
             '<div type="number" class = "number">' + data1 + '</div>' +
             '<div class="item">' + data + '</div>' +

             '<a href="javascript:undefined;" class="bin">' +
             '<img class="bin" src="Bin.png" ' +
             '</a>' + '</li>');
     }
 });
```

html

```
     </head> 
<body>
   <div id="firstPage" data-role="page">
      <div class="middle">
         <h1>My List</h1>
         <hr>
         <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <a href="#" id="enterbutton" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b ui-corner-all">Let's Shop!</a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="notesPage" data-role="page" data-theme="c">
      <div data-role="header" id="hd1">
         <h1>My Shopping List</h1>
         <a href="#addNote" data-role="button" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="notext">Add</a>
      </div>
      <br><br>
      <div role="main">
         <ul data-role="listview" id="mainList" data-inset="true">
         </ul>
      </div>
      <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="addNote" data-role="page" data-dialog="true" data-theme="c">
      <div data-role="header" id="hd3" data-theme="c">
         <h1>New Item</h1>
      </div>
      <div role="main" class="ui-content" id="hd2" data-theme="c">
         <form>
            <input type="text" name="note" id="newNote" placeholder="name...">
            <input type="text" name="amount" id="newamount" placeholder="amount...">
            <input type="submit" value="Add">
         </form>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please take the time to format your code properly. It makes it much easier for you to read, and means you'll get more accurate help much quicker.

Comment: can you post the json object also that is being stored in the localstorage. it will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

while adding the m sending the index too `appendItem(even[i], odd[i],i);` and storing the index in the data attribute `data-index` in the `.bin` anchor and while deleting m using that index to delete `var index = $(this).data('index');`

```
$(document).on('click', '#enterbutton', function() {
         $.mobile.changePage('#notesPage');
     });



     $(document).on("pagecreate", "#notesPage", function() {

         /*Load local storage items*/
         var items = localStorage.getItem('items') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items')) : items = [];
         var even = [];
         var odd = [];


         console.log(items);
         items.forEach(function(key, value) {
             if (isOdd(value + 1) == 1) {
                 even.push(key);
             } else {
                 odd.push(key);
             }
         });
         if ((0 < even.length) && (0 < odd.length)) {
             for (i = 0; i < even.length; i++) {
                 appendItem(even[i], odd[i],i);
             }
         }


         /*Add new item*/
         $('form').on('submit', function(event) {
             event.preventDefault();
             if ($('#newNote').val() == '' || $('#newamount').val() == '') {
                 alert('Input can not be left blank');
             } else {
                 var item = $('#newNote').val();
                 var inum = $('#newamount').val(); //Append this to the arrayItems;        saveToLocalStorage(item, inum);


                 //Create the new item and inject to list        appendItem(item, inum);


                 $('#mainList').listview('refresh');
                 $.mobile.changePage('#notesPage');
             }
         });
         /*Delete item*/
         $(document).on('click', '.bin', function() {
             var item = $(this).closest('li');
             var index = $(this).data('index');
             items.splice(index, 2);
             console.log(items);
             localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(items));
             $(item).slideUp();

         });


         /*Check item*/
         $(document).on('click', '.check', function() {
             var item = $(this).closest('li');
             $(item).toggleClass("checked")

         });
         /*Save data to localStorage*/
         function saveToLocalStorage(data, data1) {
             items.push(data, data1);
             console.log(items);
             localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(items));
         }

         function isOdd(num) {
             return Math.abs(num % 2);
         }

         /*Append item to html*/
         function appendItem(data, data1,index) {
             $('#mainList').append('<li class="ui-li-static ui-body-inherit ui-first-child ui-last-child">' +
                 '<input type="checkbox" class = "check" </input>' +
                 '<div type="number" class = "number">' + data1 + '</div>' +
                 '<div class="item">' + data + '</div>' +

                 '<a href="javascript:undefined;" class="bin">' +
                 '<img class="bin" data-index="'+index+'" src="Bin.png" ' +
                 '</a>' + '</li>');
         }
     });
```

try this i hope it works.

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm still having problems though, with my original code the array deletes everything in reverse order, but with your revision the first two items (first four entries in the items array) are always deleted regardless of which item I try to delete

Comment: ok, i hv an idea instead of appending/removing dom each how about make a function `render` that renders the content of the `localStorage('item')` which is an array, by doing this u don't hv to keep track what is being removed and added, since any change will be automatically rendered .